# A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2017

When I try to publish my code first project into Azure, it shows me this warning:

> Warning : A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

How can I change the target platform?

I've googled it, but what ever I've found was a sql project of data project, etc.

Comment: [How to: Change Target Platform and Publish a Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272687(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: According to your description and error message. I have created a test MVC application in my side with EF  code first. It works well.  I couldn't see this warning. Could you please tell me how you set the publish setting? Have you enable the publish sql(upload local data into azure database)? If possible, you could upload the project for us to repro the issue and find the solution.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue and cannot find any support anywhere for it.

Answer (score 4):

@David Browne's link leads to the answer, quoting directly from his link:

> **To change a project’s target platform**
>
> Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Click the Project Settings tab on the left to access the Project Settings property page.
>
> The Target platform dropdown list in this page contains all the supported SQL Server platforms that a database project can be published to. For this procedure, select SQL Azure.

Of course for this specific warning, you'll want to select:
`Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem using SSMS 2012.

The solution was:

1. Download and install [the latest version of SMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) (in my case, 2018).
2. Restar the pc.
3. Log in to my localhost server on SMSS.
4. Select my db and try again to "Deploy db to Ms Azure".

Good luck.